# GMAT LEO spacecraft simulation

Tags: low-earth-orbit, calculation, gmat

I started using GMAT, I have to design an LEO of an AEOLUS Satellite and I have the TLE of the launching. My question is how do I plug the TLE numbers into the spacecraft section (Keplerian element section specifically) in GMAT and how to calculate them?
[image: THE TLE launching]

Answer (score 2):

> ...how do I plug the TLE numbers into the spacecraft section (Keplerian element section specifically) in GMAT...?

The following answer will presuppose that you've read through the manual and determined there is no built-in function to do that.

If you didn't and there is, then just do what it says.

But I don't think there is, see for example:

- [Modelling ISS orbit in GMAT](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/59779/12102)

> I found a nice python library called TLE-tools that will read in the TLE and provides a to_orbit() method.

If there isn't then do not try to convert a TLE to Keplerian elements because TLEs are only valid when interpreted by the SGP4 propagator.

So choose an SGP4 propagator

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models
- questions tagged [sgp4](/questions/tagged/sgp4)
- https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/ (if you'd like to try Python)
- https://celestrak.org/software/tskelso-sw.php
- https://celestrak.org/software/

then put your recent, valid TLE into it, and extract [state vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_state_vectors) i.e. [x, y, z, vx, vy vz] in the (strangely named) [Earth Centered Inertial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial) frame.

- [How can Earth-Centered Inertial (ECI) coordinates be properly called "inertial" if the Earth's orbit is always accelerating towards the Sun?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40202/12102)

Then choose a few from that set at different times (say at periapsis, apoapsis, equator-crossing (i.e. ascending & descending nodes), when its over your house...) and put each of THOSE into GMAT as ECI state vectors, Then propagate each one in GMAT and see how closely they agree or disagree over time.

Then you will have learned *several things!*